# Performance Decrease by Increasing Threads Number More Than 4 in 24 Core CPU

Tags: c++, multithreading, ubuntu, multiprocessing, multicore

I have an Intel Xeon E5-2620 which has 24 on 2 CPU. I have write an application which creates 24 threads for decryption of AES using openssl. When I increase thread  number from 1 to 24 on 1 million data decryption I get a result such as following image.
[image]

The problem is when I increase thread numbers all of core which I determined are becoming 100% and because of 32GB ram of system always at least half of the ram is free which indicate that the problem is not core usage or ram limit.
I wonder to know that should I set a special parameter for increasing performance in OS level or it is process limitation which can not attain more than 4 thread in maximum performance.
I have to mention that when I execute "openssl evp ..." for testing aes encryption decryption because of process fork it increase the performance about 20 times more than one core performance.
Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: One problem is that half of the "cores" are not *actual* cores, but a kind of virtual core, emulated with some pipelining tricks. That's why you have a (small) bump when you go up above 12 threads.

Comment: Is `openssl evp` single threaded ?

Comment: There are lots of possible explanation, but we can only guess *if you don't show us the benchmark cosde* ... (Hint).

Comment: First, the processor has 6 cores (with hyper-threading) according to Intel ARK. Second, my guess is that your parallelization of the code is probably broken, but somehow you manage to stop the processor from being able to make use of Intel Boost Turbo. Therefore the cpu frequency of the (only?) core that is productively working is reduced by up to 20%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the the reason. multiple CPUs have different rams on servers which have different distances. when I created threads until 4 threads are created on one single cpu but fifth thread will be placed on second cpu which decrease performance because of not using NUMA in os.
so when I disabled cores of second cpu, performance of 6 threads increased as expected.
you can disable 7th core using following command:

```
cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/
echo 0 > cpu6/online
```

Comment: Here [Intel® Xeon® Processor E5-2620](http://ark.intel.com/products/64594/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E5-2620-15M-Cache-2_00-GHz-7_20-GTs-Intel-QPI) it shows `Max # of Memory Channels = 4`. Also, from graph time increase after 4 core. Are these things related? I guess cores might be having dedicated Memory Channels and when threads are created they are evenly distributed so that each gets its own Memory Channel  via core. So from 5th thread onwards memory contention starts. Can you please display the core/cpu-id of individual threads when only 4 threads are created?

Answer (score 0):

If multiprocessing gives a 20x speedup and equivalent multithreading only gives 2.5x, there's clearly a bottleneck in the multithreaded code. Furthermore, this bottleneck is unrelated to the hardware architecture.

It could be something in your code, or in the underlying library. It's really impossible to tell without studying both in some detail.

I'd start by looking at lock contention in your multithreaded application.